# Cygwin SSHD AuthorizedKeysCommand

Tags: ssh, cygwin, cygwin-sshd

I'm trying to setup cygwin sshd to call a script via the AuthorizedKeysCommand. I can see the error messsage in the Windows EventViewer stating that:

> sshd: PID 5178: error: Unsafe AuthorizedKeysCommand "/tmp/myscript":
> bad ownership or modes for file /tmp/myscript

The Cygwin SSHD service runs as the SYSTEM account. I've tried several options, including setting the ownership of the file to SYSTEM:SYSTEM (via chown), placing the file in /home/SYSTEM. The file is only writable by the owner and execution is granted to everyone, which seems to be compatible with that sshd expects.

Any thoughts?

Cygin version: 3.1.7(0.340/5/3)
OpenSSH: 8.4p1
Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: What does `ls -l "${scriptpath}"` say?

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM 452 Apr 12 11:21 /tmp/myscript*`.  --- I also tried with root as owner